# When changing iframe src via javascript, the whole page refreshes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, iframe

in my asp.net application I have a page That has two iframes. Above these frames are a few link buttons. When these buttons are hit, they should change the src of the two iframes. Listed below is the client side code and javascript I am using to do this. The issue is when any of these buttons are hit, instead of just changing the src of one of the iframes, the whole page refreshes. (i can tell this is refreshing because the link buttons are not available till you log in on the first page shown in the main frame, after you log in the buttons become visible via a call to the parent - window.parent.loginSuccess()   ). If one of them is then clicked, it sends you back to the log in page in the iframe and the buttons are are no longer visible.) Here is the code, does anyone see why this is happening? Thank you for your help.

```
<body id="bodysty">
<div id="fstyle" class="daform">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="master">
    <div id="topthing"> <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnControlPanel" onclientclick="CPhit()" runat="server" style="display:none">Control Panel</asp:LinkButton> <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAddClient" runat="server" onclientclick="AddClientHit()" style="display:none">Add Client</asp:LinkButton> <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnManageClients" runat="server" onclientclick="ManageClientsHit()" style="display:none">Manage Clients</asp:LinkButton> <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAdmin" runat="server" onclientclick="ManageClientsHit()" style="display:none">Admin Options</asp:LinkButton></div>
    <div id="leftcontrol">
    <iframe id="LeftIframe" runat="server" ></iframe>
        </div>
    <div id="mainbodyform">

    <iframe id="ContentIframe" runat="server" src="Login.aspx" class="mainiframe" ></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script language="javascript">
    function CPhit() {
        document.getElementById("ContentIframe").src = "LoginNotes.aspx";
    }
    function AddClientHit() {
        document.getElementById("ContentIframe").src = "NewCustomer.aspx";
    }
    function loginSuccess() {
        document.getElementById('lbtnControlPanel').style.display = 'inherit'
        document.getElementById('lbtnAddClient').style.display = 'inherit'
        document.getElementById('lbtnManageClients').style.display = 'inherit'
        document.getElementById('lbtnAdmin').style.display = 'inherit'
    }
</script>
```

There is no code in the codebehind that deals with this page, its simply for navigation. Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there any code in either of the iframes that might be messing with the parent frame?  Of code in your frame that might be acting when the iframes are finished loading?

Comment: There is code relating to the log in, i used a pagemethods call on the login page inside the frame - so it checks the log in and returns true if a valid log in, this then calls loginSuccess on the parent. This works correctly because the link buttons then show because loginSuccess is being hit on the parent page (code above) - I am getting this issue when I click on any of the link buttons after they become visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cancel the default click action of the item you are clicking on.

Simple way is to return false on the click event.

```
onclientclick="CPhit(); return false;"
```

better way is [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I will accept as an answer when the time limit has reached. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the behaviour of the button Try

```
event.stopPropagation() or  window.event.cancelBubble = true
```

in your JS functions